# Using TokensRegex for developing rule based NER and classifying entities from context words

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I am using a simple rules file given below to detect Named Entities from text. This rule is for a example like :

> Bill Gates, President and Chairman of Microsoft..

Here the first NNP postag refers to PERSON Bill Gates and the second NNP postag refers to ORGANIZATION Microsoft.

I get a null output for this.

I guess I am not sure how to capture the PERSON and ORGANIZATION entities. What changes should I make in my rules file to be bale to capture both these groups or at least one, say organization?

```
$TITLES_CORPORATE = "/chief administrative officer|cao|chief marketing officer|cmo|chief operating officer|coo|chief privacy officer|cpo|chief process officer|chief product officer|chief reputation officer|cro|chief research officer|chief restructuring officer|chief risk officer|chief science officer|cso|chief scientific Officer|chief security officer|chief services officer|chief strategy officer|chief sustainability officer|chief technology officer|vice chairman|general manager|gm|manager/";
$TITLE_PREFIXES = "/senior|executive|assistant|deputy|chief|general|staff/";


 {
      ruleType: "tokens",
      pattern:  ( [ { pos:NNP } ]+ ($TITLE_PREFIXES)? TITLES_CORPORATE /,/? /of/? [ { pos:NNP } ]+ ), 
      result: "ORGANIZATION"

       }
```

Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
     String rulesFile = "D:\\Workspace\\resource\\NERRulesFile.txt";
     String dataFile = "D:\\Workspace\\\resource\\GoldSetSentences.txt";

     Properties props = new Properties();
     props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma");
     StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
     Annotation document = new Annotation(dataFile);
     pipeline.annotate(document);
     List<CoreMap> sentences = document.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);


    //List<CoreLabel> tokens = new ArrayList<CoreLabel>();
    CoreMapExpressionExtractor extractor = CoreMapExpressionExtractor.createExtractorFromFiles(TokenSequencePattern.getNewEnv(), rulesFile);

    for (CoreMap sentence:sentences) {
      List<MatchedExpression> matched = extractor.extractExpressions(sentence);
      System.out.println(matched);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your example in terms of tokens:

```
[Bill, Gates, President, and, Chairman, of, Microsoft, Corp, .]
```

A TokensRegex rule is over TOKENS, so the regular expressions need to match tokens.  So one of your examples will not work at all since it contains multi-token expressions.

This is a pattern that matches "President and Chairman of Microsoft Corp" in the above example:

```
pattern: (/President/ /and/? /Chairman/ /of/? [{pos: NNP}]+)
```

Comment: Got it! But then how does one match multi-token expressions?Not achievable using Tokens Regex? Is there any alternative as I want to continue using the rule-based approach to detect named entities.

Comment: My example above matches a multi-token expression.  The key is you need each part of your rule to be a regex over a token.  So (/President/ /and/? /Chairman/) will match the multi-token expression "President and Chairman"

Comment: The thing is I don't want to write separate rules for every job title out there. I want to use the macros $TITLE_PREFIXES and TITLES__CORPORATE in my rule so that it can match any job title occuring in the text. I am unable to do that using this code and rules file.